# How to query the name of the current SQL Server database instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms

It is a bit of a "chicken or egg" kind of query, but can someone dreamup a query that can return the name of the current database instance in which the query executes? Believe me when I say I understand the paradox: why do you need to know the name of the database instance if you're already connected to execute the query? Auditing in a multi-database environment.

I've looked at all the @@ globals in Books Online. "`SELECT @@servername`" comes close, but I want the name of the database instance rather than the server.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT
 @@servername AS 'Server Name' -- The database server's machine name
,@@servicename AS 'Instance Name' -- e.g.: MSSQLSERVER
,DB_NAME() AS 'Database Name'
,HOST_NAME() AS 'Host Name' -- The database client's machine name
```

Comment: Add to that: `,HOST_NAME() AS 'Host Name'`

Answer (score 49):

```
SELECT DB_NAME()
```

Returns the database name.

Comment: gives me master and not server\instance.

Comment: More relevant: `SELECT HOST_NAME()`

Answer (score 5):

You can use **DB_NAME()** :

```
SELECT DB_NAME()
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you were exactly asking. As you are writing this procedure for an Auditing need I guess you're asking how do you get the current database name when the Stored Procedure exists in another database. e.g.

```
USE DATABASE1
GO
CREATE PROC spGetContext AS
SELECT DB_NAME()
GO
USE DATABASE2
GO
EXEC DATABASE1..spGetContext
/* RETURNS 'DATABASE1' not 'DATABASE2' */
```

This is the correct behaviour, but not always what you're looking for. To get round this you need to create the SP in the Master database and mark the procedure as a System Procedure. The method of doing this differs between SQL Server versions but here's the method for SQL Server 2005 (it is possible to do in 2000 with the `master.dbo.sp_MS_upd_sysobj_category` function).

```
USE MASTER
/* You must begin function name with sp_ */
CREATE FUNCTION sp_GetContext
AS
SELECT DB_NAME()
GO
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_GetContext

USE DATABASE2
/* Note - no need to reference master when calling SP */
EXEC sp_GetContext
/* RETURNS 'DATABASE2' */
```

Hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
```

Answer (score 4):

**simply use:**

```
select @@servicename
```

Comment: This solution was already mentioned in the question and does not give the desired result

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName')
```

Comment: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName') gives me a NULL

Comment: There are other properties, so you can also try `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'), SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')` and so on. See [MSDN documentation `SERVERPROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) for a list of _some_ of the properties that exist.

Comment: Flagged for moderators... doesn't work as an answer in 2019...   Correct answer is SELECT DB_NAME() which has 46 points (46th is mine).

Answer (score 0):

You can get **the instance name** of **your current database** as shown below:

```sql
SELECT @@SERVICENAME                   -- SQLEXPRESS
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName') -- SQLEXPRESS
```