# How to find server name of SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ssms

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

When I start SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I get the `Connect to Server` login window with a blank textbox for `Server name`. I have tried a lot of names, but I couldn't solve it.

How can I find / get the server name?

Comment: See also: [How can I query the name of the current SQL Server database instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129861/)

Comment: I you wanted to know to which SQL-Server you are connected inside [tag:ssms] then see here [How to view connection string from within ssms](https://serverfault.com/questions/187465/can-i-view-my-mssql-connection-string-from-within-sql-server-management-studio/666344#666344)

Answer (score 202):

Open up `SQL Server Configuration Manager` (search for it in the Start menu). Click on `SQL Server Services`. The instance name of SQL Server is in parenthesis inline with `SQL Server`  service. If it says **MSSQLSERVER**, then it's the default instance. To connect to it in Management Studio, just type `.` (dot) OR `(local)` and click Connect. If the instance name is different, then use `.\[instance name]` to connect to it (for example if the instance name is **SQL2008**, connect to `.\SQL2008`).

Also make sure `SQL Server` and `SQL Server Browser` services are running, otherwise you won't be able to connect.

**Edit:**

Here's a screenshot of how it looks like on my machine. In this case, I have two instances installed: `SQLExpress` and `SQL2008`.

[image]

Comment: What do I do if the list on the right hand side of the screen is empty for me?

Comment: @FilipB.Vondrášek That means you don't have a local instance installed on your computer. You'll need to rerun the setup.exe file to add a new instance.

Comment: Turns out I installed only Management Studio which doesn't come with a server. I downloaded a version with Advanced Tools and now everything works as supposed. :)

Comment: @FilipVondrášek where did you install the advanced tools from? I just installed sql server 16 and 17 from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms). I can't seem to get the local instance name

Comment: @adiga I'm afraid I won't be of much help here anymore, it's been a long time and I haven't used MS SQL Server for quite a long time as well now. :)

Comment: @FilipVondrášek that okay. I installed different versions of SQL server hoping to get an option to install the server. Finally worked when I installed SQL express, there was an option to create servers as well. Now it's working. Microsft, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Filip Vondrášek it happens when you have only client-side like management studio but do not have SQL server express which has many services like creating an instance.

Comment: `.` worked with MSSQLSERVER 2019...THANKS

Comment: I love how this is still not marked as the accepted answer lol.

Answer (score 134):

Run this Query to get the name

> SELECT @@SERVERNAME

Comment: If you cant login, You can use UserName <.> (Dot)  and Password <password> to initial login after  you can use SELECT @@SERVERNAME  to find Server name :)

Comment: you cant run a query if you aren't loged in.

Comment: While this does not answer the exact question asked - it is exactly the answer I was looking for.  I strongly suspect it will be useful to many others as well. In my case I have a Prod & Dev Server with very similar data, and at one point I was unsure which I was connected to c  This was an elegant & clean way of finding out without disconnecting or closing my query window.  Thanks!

Comment: Error running query: column "servername" does not exist LINE 250: SELECT @@SERVERNAME ^

Comment: Surprisingly, doesn't work correctly.
For me it returns DESKTOP-XXXXXXX which I think is the default PC name when I installed windows. 
The actual PC name is no longer that. So it's something to take into account.

Answer (score 77):

Open [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).exe (<kbd>WINDOWS + R</kbd> type `cmd` and press Enter)

and run this

```
SQLCMD -L
```

You will get list of SQL Server instance

#### 3rd party edit

[image: CMD.exe_with_SQLCMD_and_OSQL_Result]

Comment: can you explain in cmd?

Comment: I usually use Windows + R, type cmd and press Enter. Then use SQLCMD -L   (You can use "osql -L"  too at CMD)

Comment: +1 Did it fo rme. Not sure why others are telling you to run a query when you can't without connecting to an instance...

Comment: Yes this is the only right method... remaining all others are not always works...
Its not always as like this... many more toss goes...
In my example,eventhough it shows MSSQLSERVER, but it wont work with that... instead it works with (local)

Answer (score 61):

**Note:**  To connect to server on SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS), we must first install SQL Server.

So steps to proceed are as

**Step 1** :  Downloads and Install  [Microsoft SQL Server 2022](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)

**Step 2** : Downloads and Install [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

If still not able to see the Server name on SSMS, have a look at these three screen:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Solved My Problem, Thanks

Comment: I try to check it and my Local Servers is also Blank, what should I do?

Comment: @MathewMagante try restarting the system

Answer (score 55):

the default server name is your computer name, but you can use "." (Dot) instead of local server name.

another thing you should consider is maybe you installed sql server express edition. in this case you must enter ".\sqlexpress" as server name.

Comment: I have installed sqlexpress and adding ".\sqlexpress" in server name worked for me

Answer (score 30):

As mentioned by @Khaneddy2013, the cmd **SQLCMD -L**
returns no server name when I run. Bcz I only have installed the SSMS (local db and server were not installed).
After tried installing *SqlLocaLDB* and *SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU*(32 bit OS) I was able to connect. And now the cmd window shows the server names too.
[image]

Comment: just because its an old question doesnt mean we cant add to it. i found this to be the answer i was looking for.

Comment: Hi, can you explain more detail how server was installed. I already install localdb, sql server management studio and SQLEXPRADV_64_ENU (64 bit op). I still get no servername when execute command sqlcmd -L.

Answer (score 22):

There are many ways mentioned above. But I use rather simple way (well not simple as **SELECT @@SERVERNAME**). When you start SQL server management studio you will prompt below GUI

[image]

In there Server name is your server name (There may have multiple servers according to you dev environment choose correct one). Hope this helps :)

Comment: Not always true. You can type an alias in here, e.g. one held by DNS, to go to a defined server name. However SELECT @@SERVERNAME will report the server's computer name, not the alias you typed into the connection manager.

Answer (score 15):

start -> CMD ->  (Write comand)   SQLCMD -L     first line is Server name if Server name is (local)    Server name is : YourPcName\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Worked like a charm to me. Thanks Mate.

Answer (score 11):

given the following examples

- SQL Instance Name: MSSQLSERVER
- Port: 1433
- Hostname: MyKitchenPC
- IPv4: 10.242.137.227
- DNS Suffix: dir.svc.mykitchencompany.com

here are your possible servernames:

- localhost\MSSQLSERVER
- localhost,1433\MSSQLSERVER
- MyKitchenPC,1433\MSSQLSERVER
- 10.242.137.227,1433\MSSQLSERVER
- MyKitchenPC.dir.svc.mykitchencompany.com,1433\MSSQLSERVER

Comment: The OP asked "How can I find / get the server name?"

Answer (score 6):

Step1: Ensure SQLEXPRESS and LocalDB installed on your system
Go to SQL SERVER Configuration Manager => SQL Server Service

If nothing listed for SQL Server services, install below components (for 64 bit OS) 
1.  SqlLocalDB
2.  SQLEXPR_x64_ENU
3.  SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU
4.  SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU

Step2: Open Management Studios
Enter . (Dot) as server name and click on Connect
 [enter image description here][2]
Else
Enter  .\SQLEXPRESS as server name and click on connect

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem first time.

In the Connect to Server dialog box, verify the default settings, and then click Connect. To connect, the Server name box must contain the name of the computer where SQL Server is installed. If the Database Engine is a named instance, the Server name box should also contain the instance name in the format: computer_name\instance_name.

So for example i solved the problem like this: I typed in the server name: Alex-PC\SQLEXPRESS

Then it should work. for more see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25ffaea6-0eee-4169-8dd0-1da417c28fc6

Answer (score 4):

Try using a . or localhost as server name, might work a few times.

Answer (score 3):

simply type .\sqlexpress as the Server Name

Answer (score 1):

Typing `sp_helpserver` will give you a list. As others have noted, there are multiple ways, some with alias' and such.  This stored proc may return multiple lines but could get you closer to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed SQL Server.

If not, follow this link and download.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Once SQL server is installed successfully.
You will get server name.
Refer to the below picture:

[image]

Comment: How to open this window again? I just closed it and I don't know how to open this window again.

Answer (score 1):

The game changer for me is  just try the below exact servername

(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

1.you can run following command.

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"';
GO

you can read instance name using Registry. Ingore null values.

2.using inbuilt standard Report.

select instance--> right click->Reports-->Standard Reports-->server Dashbords [image]

Comment: and how you run it if u need the name before connecting to server?

Answer (score 0):

Please Install SQL Server Data Tools from link ([SSDT](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2052454))

You can also Install it when you are installing Visual Studio there is Option **"Data Storage and Processing"** you must be select while installing Visual Studio

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On installing the sql server 2019 management studio the default server name will be : localhost\SQLEXPRESS
default connection string is :
Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;

Answer (score 0):

only right method is by checking "SQLCMD -L"  in cmd prompt...
remaining all others are not always works... many more toss goes...
In my example,eventhough it shows MSSQLSERVER in configuration manager, but it wont work with that... instead it works with (local) as per sqlcmd -L
[image]

Answer (score -1):

my problem was that when connecting to SQL Database in the add reference wizard, to find the SERVERNAME. i found it by: running a query(SELECT @@SERVERNAME) inside SQL management studio and the reusl was my servername. I put that in my server name box and it worked all fine.

Comment: This answer does not add anything to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18765207/4751173).