# ASP.NEt Identity Not working or registering

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am currently developing a web app but I can not register not even a first User.
The Webconfig  has its connection string working normally. I can update delete or create the app products and the database updates immediately which indicates( i think) that the connection string its working fine. I creted a new proyect in MVC I did not change anything and stil can not register a user
Its shows after 30-60 sec the following error. The reason I mention the connection string is that the error mention a SQL exception  and talk about wrong connection string  but apparently it is working fine and this is a new unchanged MVC proyect
Thanks

> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 153:            { Line 154:                var user = new
>   ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email }; Line
>   155:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,
>   model.Password); Line 156:                if (result.Succeeded) Line
>   157:                {
>
> Source File: C:\Users\IronMan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\training\IDTest\IDTest\Controllers\AccountController.cs 
>   Line: 155
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
>   locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
>   Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
>   feature is enabled.)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +92
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod
>   authType) +372
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +172
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +849
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionSt

and more like above

Comment: possibly try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111611/entity-framework-6-the-server-was-not-found-or-was-not-accessible

Comment: This answer might help you - [How to add ASP.NET MVC5 Identity Authentication to existing database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651342/how-to-add-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-existing-database/25651908#25651908)

Comment: Hey Win That was exactly what was happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find DataContext class
2. Set default value of connection string key as it written in web.config file

I think that problem is that when you trying to create user, it creates data context which can't find your's cnnection string.

Comment: So I found that the controller for the Registration was using the default connection string I changed to the connection string that I was using to generate my tables and now it works ok BUt