# SQL server connection issue ,while logging in with sql server authentication?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2012

I am using WINDOWS 10 PRO 64 OS and Installed SQL server 2012 with both Windows authentication and SQL server authentication both mixed.When I am trying to login into the SQL server with SQL server Authentication with default Username as :sa
and Password as :123,it is throwing error unable to connect to the server ,Error:233.I have tried every thing by enabling tcp/ip and Named pipes.Also changed the windows fire wall setting for port.Below is the screen shot of the error.Please find me the solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHQMJ.png)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the correct password? Try it with a blank password.

Answer (score 0):

try (localhost)/INSTANCE_NAME. For example, I'm assuming your machine name is MADHUBABU-PC, so try `MADHUBABU-PC\SQLEXPRESS`. (I'm not sure what you named your sql instance.)
Here is a nice link to find your instance name: [How to find server name of SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio)