# Server name on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Management Studio on my PC, and when I try to connect to a server, it shows this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

I don't know what should be the server name. How can I connect to a server?

Comment: You have only installed a client for SQL Server. The server name you will need to find out from whomever told you that you need SSMS to perform whatever tasks you've been asked to perform.

Comment: Management Studio is **just** the management program. It connects to Sql Server to let you manage tables, run queries, and other tasks. It does not actually host any database by itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find server name of SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: try type . (just dot) or local on server name text box , if your instance was default one (MSSQLSERVER)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enable protocals
test TCP/ip Connectivity
refer following link
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Run the command SQLCMD -L in a command prompt and you will see your available server names. 
If you need additional resources check out this answer:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44171/find-all-version-of-sql-server-on-a-network