# How to know my server name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms, server-name

I installed SQL Server but I forgot my server name and now that I install SQL Server Management Studio, it needs the server name.

How can I get server name again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find server name of SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio)

Answer (score 5):

You can get **your server name** with **Transact-SQL(T-SQL)** as shown below:

```sql
SELECT @@SERVERNAME                    -- DESKTOP-OVPADTC\SQLEXPRESS
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName')   -- DESKTOP-OVPADTC\SQLEXPRESS
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed SQL Server on your local machine, you can get to the installed server using

```
.
(local)
localhost
YourMachineName
```

as the server/instance name.

If you installed SQL Server **Express** with the defaults, you can reach your instance with:

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
(local)\SQLEXPRESS
localhost\SQLEXPRESS
YourMachineName\SQLEXPRESS
```

Otherwise, you need to go to Start Menu > SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager and see which SQL Server services are running:

[image]

If you find a Service Type = SQL Server with a State = Running, the instance name is provided in the brackets behind the "SQL Server" in the `Name` column - here it is `SQL2014`. In that case, you can connect to this running SQL Server instance on your local machine using:

```
.\SQL2014
(local)\SQL2014
localhost\SQL2014
YourMachineName\SQL2014
```

If the instance name (in brackets) is `MSSQLSERVER`, this means it's the default, unnamed instance - and you can connect to it with just one of the first four options - just the "local machine server name" - no instance needs to be provided.

Answer (score 1):

When the ssms's launched, the "Connect to Server" appears first,

then in the `Server name` field it'll have already selected (probably your pc name if you gave default on server installation) the server name.

If it isn't there, then click on it (Server name drop down)
<Browse for more...>
then on the popup "Browse for Servers"
click on "Database Engine"
and you can find your server name there.
There will be only one server name there ,if this is the first server you've created.
Click on the server name and hit OK!