# SQL: When using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES How do I specify a database name and a server name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In the code below, I am able to specify the table name and schema that I want to query with Table name and Table schema. How do I specify the database name and server name that I want to query?

I have tried DATABASE_NAME, DB_NAME and SERVER_NAME. None of them work.

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) AS TABLECOUNT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE 
 TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = '[TABLE_NAME]
```

Comment: We can use directly server name and database also. See my answer update. I have already checked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can select database, table and server-name :

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS TABLECOUNT, @@SERVERNAME as 'serverName' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'CALCULATION_SCHEDULE' 
and @@SERVERNAME ='xx' and TABLE_CATALOG ='database name'
```

click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio) to know more about the serverName

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `TABLE_CATALOG` for passing database name. In SQL Server this column contains the database name that contains that table as shown below.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS TABLECOUNT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'CALCULATION_SCHEDULE'
AND TABLE_CATALOG = '<Your Database Name>'
```

You can also pass directly server name and database name as shown below.

```
SELECT * FROM [ServerName].[DatabaseName].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where ---.
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. What about to specify a server name?

Comment: @Suraj Kumar, worth to mention that it will work only for tables that are present in a current database, such select will not check existence of objects from other database

Comment: @AlexanderVolok We can use directly server name and database also. See my answer update. I have already checked that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no table or view that enumerates all tablesof all databases, you have to explicitly specify database:

1. Directly in query

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(1) AS TABLECOUNT
   FROM [dbname].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'CALCULATION_SCHEDULE'   ;
   ```
2. Via "USE"

   ```
   USE [dbname]
   SELECT COUNT(1) AS TABLECOUNT
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'CALCULATION_SCHEDULE'   ;
   ```
3. In your connection string

---

Regarding a Server Name, it is possible only via system variables like @@SERVERNAME or SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'):

```
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'CALCULATION_SCHEDULE'   
AND SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') = 'YourServer' ;
```

Comment: We can use directly server name and database also. See my answer update. I have already checked that.

Comment: @SurajKumar, of course catalog_name can be used, but it always contain a name of the database where it resides, so it has limited usefulnes. The same can be achieved with DB_NAME() = '<Your Database Name>' in case of OP