# Trying to insert data into a MSSQL server using php but getting error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, t-sql

So i just bought a Microsoft azure SQL server, and im trying to connect to it using php on my website however it keeps throwing an error saying "Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\data.php on line 50

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\data.php on line 50
Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known." Can someone give me precise instructions on how to fix this issue.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$firstname = $_POST["inputFirstName"];

$lastname = $_POST["inputLastName"];

$email = $_POST["emailaddress"];
//$email = "";

$discordid = $_POST["discordid"];

$stuff = array($firstname, $lastname, $email, $discordid);
//echo implode(" ",$stuff);

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'APIKEYHERE'
);
if(!empty($stripe->customers->all(['email' => $email, 'limit' => 1])->data[0])){
$yo = $stripe->customers->all(['email' => $email, 'limit' => 1])->data[0]->id;
echo("You are already in our system your customer ID is: " . $yo);
}
else{
  echo("All good");
  
  $stripe->customers->create([
      'name' => $firstname . " " . $lastname,
      'email' => $email, 
    'description' => $discordid,
  ]);
  //add free subscription
  $stripe->subscriptions->create([
    'customer' => $stripe->customers->all(['email' => $email, 'limit' => 1])->data[0]->id,
    'items' => [
      ['price' => ''],
    ],
  ]);

  // Create connection
  $servername = "";
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "";
  
  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tblCustomer (DiscordID, CustID, DiscordName)
  VALUES ('111', '55', 'John Smith')";
  
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
  
  $conn->close();

  //create and redirect user to billing session
  header("Location: ".$stripe->billingPortal->sessions->create([
    'customer' => $stripe->customers->all(['email' => $email, 'limit' => 1])->data[0]->id,
    'return_url' => 'https://www.google.com/',
  ])->url);
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For the time being im just trying to do a get request, just to make sure i can get this going.

Comment: after your insert.. you have three = signs... shouldn't that be only 2 like ==

Comment: @harry idk i copied that template from the internet. Ill give it a shot tho.

Comment: nope still doesnt work. ERROR: 

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\data.php on line 50

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\data.php on line 50
Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: I'm guessing.. where it says //creta connection . you have actually entered all your connections setting and not blank? Just asking the obvious!

Comment: Yes i have entered all my connection settings

Comment: I feel like it has to do with these dumb drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Warning "No such host is known" occur because "Host" is not set properly.

Recheck the 'servername'

To know about
[How to find server name of SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio)

This worked for me :

```
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "test";
```