# How to find out if SQL Server is installed with default instance or named instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement where I need to find out *whether SQL is installed with default instance or named instance*.

Can someone please help me here how to find it?

Thanks in advance,
Sasikumar.

Comment: I think this is same http://stackoverflow.com/a/18070284/1692632

Answer (score 11):

Go to `Start > All programs > SQL Server xxxx > Configuration Tools > Configuration Manager` and have a look:

[image]

If the entry `SQL Server` has `(MSSQLSERVER)` after it --> it's the (unnamed) default instance.

Otherwise, you'll find the **instance name** in brackets after the `SQL Server`